# Efficiently loading product data via model

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute, model

I have a custom attribute for product called `warehouse` of type drop down.

In order to load the `Sku => Warehouse` (get assigned value for each product) updates between dates via models; I do the following:

```
// Load warehouse attribute options
$warehouse_options = array();
$options = array();
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'warehouse');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
}
$attribute = null;
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $warehouse_options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}
$options = null;

// Load all products updated since last sync
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array(
    'from' => $datetime_from,
    'to' => $datetime_to,
    'date' => true
));

// Init results
$results = array(
    'ServerDateTime' => $datetime_now,
    'Mapping' => array()
);

// Build results
foreach ($collection as $p) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p->getId());
    $results['Mapping'][] = array(
        'Sku' => $product->getSku(),
        'Warehouse' => isset($warehouse_options[$product->getWarehouse()]) ? $warehouse_options[$product->getWarehouse()] : ''
    );
    $product = null;
}
$collection = null;
```

This works, but quite slow as each product is getting loaded, so if I had `3000` products, thats `3000+` queries.

Is there a way to optimise this so I can load the desired data with minimal amount of query & processing?

---

I have tried to use just the collection like this using `addAttributeToSelect`:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku', 'warehouse');
```

However, the returned `$collection->getData()` does not contain the field `warehouse`. Here's an example response array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [entity_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [updated_at] => 2015-07-07 15:35:35
            [sku] => C13S041061
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like in the example `addAttributeToSelect` is used incorrectly.
This method has following signature:

`addAttributeToSelect($attribute, $joinType = false)`

Replace `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku', 'warehouse');` with

`$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku')->addAttributeToSelect('warehouse');`

Comment: I am afraid i am still NOT getting the warehouse value back. It only works if i explictly load the product via model.

Comment: Is this an EAV attribute?